# Platform-based property binding in XAML fails

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I wrote the XAML and C# code below to set `IsVisible` property of an `ActivityIndicator` to `True` on Android and iOS. C# code in the codebehind binds the same property to `IsBusy` property of the binding context on Windows. This code works as expected on all platforms.

```
# XAML Code
<ActivityIndicator x:Name="AI" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsBusy}" IsVisible="True"  IsRunning="{Binding Path=IsBusy}"/>

# C# Code
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Windows)
{
    AI.SetBinding(IsVisibleProperty, new Binding(nameof(ViewModel.IsBusy)));
}
```

I want to have the same behavior using XAML only. I tried the code snippets below none of which worked.

```
# 1
# Compiles. On Windows throws System.InvalidCastException: 
# 'Unable to cast object of type 'Xamarin.Forms.Binding' 
# to type 'System.Boolean'.'
<ActivityIndicator x:Name="AI" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsBusy}" IsRunning="{Binding Path=IsBusy}">
    <ActivityIndicator.IsVisible>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="True"/>
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="True"/>
            <On Platform="Windows" Value="{Binding Path=IsBusy}"/>
        </OnPlatform>
    </ActivityIndicator.IsVisible>
</ActivityIndicator>

# 2
# Doesn't compile. Gives an error saying "No property, 
# bindable property, or event found for 'IsVisible'"
<ActivityIndicator x:Name="AI" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsBusy}" IsVisible="True" IsRunning="{Binding Path=IsBusy}">
    <ActivityIndicator.IsVisible>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="BindingBase">
            <On Platform="Windows" Value="{Binding Path=IsBusy}"/>
        </OnPlatform>
    </ActivityIndicator.IsVisible>
</ActivityIndicator>

# 3
# Doesn't compile. Gives an error saying "No property, 
# bindable property, or event found for 'IsVisible'"
<ActivityIndicator x:Name="AI" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsBusy}" IsVisible="True" IsRunning="{Binding Path=IsBusy}">
    <ActivityIndicator.IsVisible>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Binding">
            <On Platform="Windows" Value="{Binding Path=IsBusy}"/>
        </OnPlatform>
    </ActivityIndicator.IsVisible>
</ActivityIndicator>

# 4
# Compiles. On Windows throws System.InvalidCastException: 
# 'Unable to cast object of type 'Xamarin.Forms.Binding' 
# to type 'System.Boolean'.'
<ActivityIndicator x:Name="AI" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsBusy}" IsVisible="True" IsRunning="{Binding Path=IsBusy}">
    <ActivityIndicator.IsVisible>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean">
            <On Platform="Windows">
                <Binding Path="IsBusy" />
            </On>
        </OnPlatform>
    </ActivityIndicator.IsVisible>
</ActivityIndicator>
```

Is it possible to do this in XAML at all?

Comment: I don't think you can set both the `IsVisible` attribute and the `ActivityIndicator.IsVisible` element at the same time like that.

Comment: @BradleyUffner It seems like that's not a problem. None of the XAML snippets above work with or without IsVisible attribute anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure why `BindingBase` option is not working, but for the rest of the cases, it is clear that the issue is type-mismatch.

In order to get around that I guess you can use a style setter to provide defaults while overriding them using `OnPlatform`:

```
//App or Page resources to set default properties 
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Style TargetType="ActivityIndicator" x:Key="AIStyle">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=IsBusy}" />
        <Setter Property="IsRunning" Value="{Binding Path=IsBusy}" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>

//And use following to define control
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
    <On Platform="Android, iOS">
        <ActivityIndicator IsVisible="true" Style="{StaticResource AIStyle}" />
    </On>
    <On Platform="Windows">
        <ActivityIndicator IsVisible="{Binding Path=IsBusy}" Style="{StaticResource AIStyle}" />
    </On>
</OnPlatform>
```